# How do I change backend for company?

Tags: company-mode

Recently I have discovered tabnine, a really good completion backend. I wanted to use it in emacs. So I went through the installation procedure and now I have it. But when I M-x company-diag, it shows me that I am using company-yasnippet in major mode python. I want to use tabnine instead. How do I do that?

```
Emacs 27.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) of 2020-08-28 on juergen
Company 0.9.13

company-backends: ((company-anaconda)
 company-capf company-yasnippet company-tabnine)

Used backend: company-yasnippet
Major mode: python-mode
```

This is company-diag.

Answer (score 1):

A few things.

1. `company` decides its backend based on the variable `company-backends`. If you want a specific auto-completion backend, you must specify it in your `init.el` file.

In general, you can read documentation on variables by using `M-x apropos-variable`.

2. To add a backend to company, call `(add-to-list 'company-backends '(<backend name>))`

For example, to add Elisp completion, there is a backend called `company-elisp` that comes with company.

To use this, you run `(add-to-list 'company-backend '(company-elisp))`.

This will add `company-elisp` to the list of backends that `company` decides to use.

3. Company runs through its list of backends in `company-backends` and performs a test to see if it should run a given backend for your current mode.

**The first to pass the test is used. All others are ignored.**

Now, looking at `company-anaconda`, it recommends:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "company"
  '(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-anaconda))
```

or, if you want both `company-anaconda` and `company-capf` together:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "company"
 '(add-to-list 'company-backends '(company-anaconda :with company-capf)))
```

Finally, you **must** add:
`(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'anaconda-mode)`

Looking at the source code for `company-anaconda` reveals that you **must** enable `anaconda-mode` for `company` to choose the `company-anaconda` backend.

Comment: I like your idea, which helps me to solve a problem in emacs-lisp-mode (when writing comments in this mode, the company always pop up.)